# Prove that if $k\ge 1\,$ and $\,a^k\equiv 1\pmod{\! n}$ then $\gcd(a,n)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime such that $a^p-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Prove that $\gcd(a,p) = 1$.

We know from Fermat's Little Theorem that $a^{p-1}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ if and only if $\gcd(a,p) = 1$, but how do we use this to solve the question?

Comment: Um, don't let memorizing theorems make you lose your common sense.  If p is prime the only numbers *not* relatively prime to it are multiples of p.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\gcd(a,p) \neq 1$. That is assume that $p$ divides $a$. That is, there is a $m$ such that $a = mp$. Then 
$$
a^{p} - 1 = (mp)^p - 1 = m^pp^p - 1 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}.
$$

Comment: @user19405892 you cannot as it is false, *and* you did not ask this.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of an odd question, but if you really want to know this:

As you remarked correctly $a^{p-1} -1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ for $\gcd(a,p)=1$. 
It follows that $a^{p} -a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ for those $a$.  And if $\gcd(a,p)\neq 1$ then it is $p$ and thus $a^{p} -a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ also in that case as $a$ itself is $0 \pmod{p}$.

Thus $a^{p}-a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ for all $a$. Hence $a^{p}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ if and only if $a-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ that is $a \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. This implies in particular that $\gcd(a,p)=1$.

(It's possible that the question was intended with $p-1$ instead of $p$, but then that's part of Fermat little theorem, so you know it anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Even more is true:

> If $a$ and $b$ are integers and $n\in\mathbb N^+$ such that $a^n-1\equiv 0\pmod b$, then $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

What you want is then the special case where $n$ and $b$ both happen to equal the same prime.

Proof. $a^n-1\equiv 0 \pmod b$ means that there is $k$ such that $a^n-1=kb$ which is the same as $a^{n-1}a+(-k)b=1$, so by Bezout's identity $\gcd(a,b)$ must be $1$.

Comment: You don't need [Bézout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). It's a lot simpler to prove it by contradiction: if $\gcd(a,b)>1$, then there exists a prime $p$ such that $p\mid a,b$, so $p\mid a^n-kb=1$, contradiction.

Comment: @user236182: Yes, that's part of the proof of the lemma, but I for one find it just as easy not to re-derive that each time I need it.

Comment: Or directly: notice $\gcd(a,b)\mid a,b$, so $\gcd(a,b)\mid a^n-kb=1$, so $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Notice that Bézout's lemma claims quite a lot more than this very elementary fact.

Comment: @user236182: Yes, that's part of the proof of the lemma, but I for one find it just as easy not to re-derive that each time I need it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the bar notation could make it an easier matter:

In the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the equation $a^p-1\equiv 0 \pmod{ p}$ simply means

$\displaystyle\left(\overline{a}\right)^p=\overline{1}$.

And $\gcd(a,p)=1$ if and only if $\overline{a}\neq\overline{0}$, which is quite obvious from the above equation.

Answer (score 0):

Um, don't let memorizing theorems make you lose your common sense.

If $p$ is prime the only numbers not relatively prime to it are multiples of $p$ and $(kp)^p \equiv 0 \mod p$.

=======

A *far* stronger result would be $ma -1 \equiv \mod p \implies \gcd(a,p) = 1$ regardless of whether $p$ is prime or not or whether $m = a^{p-1}$ or any number.

Oh, and duh! If $a^p = 1 \mod p$ then $a \equiv 1 \mod p$.  That is a much more interesting and less trivial question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a special case of the general fact that $\,a\,$ invertible mod $\,n\,$ implies $\,\gcd(a,n)= 1.\,$ Indeed, $\,aj\equiv 1\pmod{n}\,\Rightarrow\, aj+kn = 1\ $ so $\ d\mid a,n\Rightarrow\, d\mid 1,\,$ therefore $\,\gcd(a,n) = 1$.

OP is a special case since $\,{\rm mod}\ p\!:\  a^p-1\equiv 0\, \Rightarrow a(a^{p-1})\equiv 1\,$ so $\,a\,$ is invertible mod $\,p.$

**Remark** $\ $ The converse is also true, i.e. $\,\gcd(a,n) = 1\,\Rightarrow\,a\,$ is invertible mod $\,n,\,$ since by the Bezout identity for the gcd $\, \gcd(a,n) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, aj+kn = 1\,$ for some integers $\,j,k.\,$ Reducing this equation mod $\,n\,$ we obtain the congruence $\,aj\equiv 1\pmod n,\,$ i.e. $\,a^{-1}\equiv j\pmod n$

That fact that $\ a\,$ is invertible mod $\,n\iff \gcd(a,n)= 1\ $ is  *fundamental* and ubiquitous in elementary number theory, so one should be sure to be intimately familiar with it.